# Problems with new monitor: Slow, inaccurate with relation to mouse and slow the computer

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, performance, asus

For a long time I have used a laptop, and I have had an external monitor. I have extended the monitor of the laptop and used two monitors. I have bought a new external monitor, much larger than the previous one (28 inch).

My problems with the new monitor are:

1. The picture is "refreshed" slowly. (Although I don't watch movies/play games, I still see the slowlyness of the refreshment)
2. The mouse is not accurate on the screen. i.e, when I try to move the mouse to some direction in a straight line, it moves in a "twisted" line. When I move the mouse over the internal screen, it moves appropriately.
3. I feel that the computer is slower when it is connected to the new screen.
4. Each move of the mouse is "heavy". Moving the mouse from one end to another end in the internal monitor takes a small move of my mouse. But moving the mouse from one end to another in the external monitor, takes a very large move of the mouse. (I don't think it is because the phisical size of the external monitor because moving the mouse in the external screen takes MUCH larger move).

I tried to use the laptop with another monitor, (tried two other smaller monitors), and none of these problems happened.

My internal monitor is about 13 inch. My usages are basics (internet, office, a little bit of music, etc). The monitor that I bought is Asus VP28UQGL. I am using Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Try updating BIOS, Chipset, Video and Mouse package drivers from the manufacturer's support website. Then do a final restart and test.

Comment: _"when I try to move the mouse to some direction in a straight line, it moves in a "twisted" line"_ - this is an unrelated problem. The monitor doesn't know what's a cursor and what's not. My guess is that it's lack of movement precision caused by insufficient visual feedback.

Comment: The VP28UQGL is a 4k monitor. Were the other monitors 4k? If not I expect your video card is simply not powerful enough.

Comment: Try to change Mouse pointers settings, like pointer scheme, pointer shadow, pointer speed and so on. (Control Panel > Mouse > Pointers/Pointer Options)

Comment: @davidgo No, they weren't.